# Image area getting too much enlarged when using GeoImage from 'ol-ext/source/GeoImage'. How to set its extent and projection correctly?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, extents

I am adding an ImageLayer in openlayers using the [ol-ext/source/GeoImage](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html) so that I can support rotation of the image also.
I have done something like this:

```
    import GeoImage from 'ol-ext/source/GeoImage';
    
    
    imageLayer() {
      const imageLayer = new ImageLayer(); 
      
      const source = new GeoImage({
                             url: imgUrl,
                             projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                             imageExtent: [-4.2750075, -11.17501447, 4.2750075, 11.17501447],
                             imageCenter: ol.proj.fromLonLat(center),
                             imageRotate: Number(30*Math.PI/180),
                             imageScale: [1, 1]
                           });
      imageLayer.setSource(source);
    }
```

This creates an image in a very much large area. But if I use Static Image as source it gets rendered just fine.
I can not use Static image since I have to provide rotation as well.

Comment: `imageExtent` definition is missing in the above code. Please edit your question and add `imageExtent` definition.

Comment: You have a bit of a mess with CRS and coordinates here. What CRS do you use/want to use? What is your map view CRS?

Comment: What would then be the reason for `code: 'EPSG:27700'` in projection definition?

Comment: Now, seeing all your code and you answer about CRS used, things just don't go together. First, you map view projection is `EPSG:3857`, which is default OpenLayers projection. Second, I don't understand why are you defining your own projection at all, and then why using `EPSG:27700` id, which is official id for British National Grid. And third, when map view CRS is projected CRS, all your coordinates used as input to OpenLayers methods/functions should be converted to that CRS before being used,  just like this one for view center: `center: olProj.fromLonLat([-71.033069962, 42.212971846])`

Comment: And one more thing: you have `imageExtent` option in GeoImage creation, which will be ignored. And center of image `[-71.0330697276263, 42.2129714271348]` is outside the extent you are using here and there in your code. I would recommend georeferencing your image with ol-ext http://viglino.github.io/Map-georeferencer/, and then use calculated parameters for GeoImage creation.

Comment: Just to understand can you tell then why does this work while using Static image and not GeoImage?

Comment: No, I can't tell, since I don't have values of `${this.latitude}` and `${this.longitude}`. And I also don't understand how it can work correctly, since image is not rotated.

Comment: this.latitude and this.longitude are the center coordinates of image. And while using static image just the size of the image fits perfectly but not rotated.

Comment: So these coordinates are `[-71.0330697276263, 42.2129714271348]`?

Comment: These cordinates([-71.0330697276263, 42.2129714271348]) are same as this.longitude and this.latitude. I have directly provided these value in example above. But in actual it is coming from backend and is not hard coded

Comment: I have changed the imageCenter of geoImage to olProj.fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]) but now the image is not shown at all

Comment: Before I put up an answer, just want to make sure: is this image small patch of 19.5m x 46.7m size in the Blue Hill Cemetery?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your idea with using custom Mercator projection for overlayed image is to put origin of projection to the center of image and consequently image extent is just offset of lower left corner and upper right corner from the center. I couldn't make this work.

It's much more simple to use default OpenLayers Mercator CRS `EPSG:3857`. For this purpose first projected image center `imgCenter` is calculated from center's longitude and latitude:

```
var imgCenterLngLat = [-71.0330697276263, 42.2129714271348];
var imgCenter = ol.proj.fromLonLat(imgCenterLngLat);
```

The image extent is calculated from center coordinate and corner offsets:

```
var imgOffsetsFromCenter = [-9.750015, -23.35002894, 9.750015, 23.35002894];
var imgExtent = [
  imgCenter[0] + imgOffsetsFromCenter[0],
  imgCenter[1] + imgOffsetsFromCenter[1],
  imgCenter[0] + imgOffsetsFromCenter[2],
  imgCenter[1] + imgOffsetsFromCenter[3]
];
```

Standard unrotated static image layer source is then simply created with:

```
 const imageSource1 = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  url: 'img/image.png',
  imageExtent: imgExtent
});
```

On the other hand GeoImage source needs three options to be used when creating layer source: `imageCenter`, `imageRotate` and `imageScale`. The first two might be known, but I couldn't find any docs about how to calculate the third one `imageScale`. The only way mentioned in ol-ext docs is to use ol-ext georeferencer at http://viglino.github.io/Map-georeferencer/. Using this, I got the following values for options for test image, which was rotated for 15 degrees:

```
var imageSource2 = new ol.source.GeoImage({
  url: 'img/image.png',
  imageCenter: [-7907365.155115354,5192936.093016684],
  imageScale: [0.2760981681922128,0.2760981681922128],
  imageRotate: -0.2777331904109953,
});
```

With `imageSource1` (ImageStatic) I got the following result for test image:

[image]

With properly rotated and sized `imageSource2` (GeoImage) I got desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are two questions I have. First what is the imgOffsetsFromCenter here? if you could provide its definition. Second, how can I calculate the scale of the image if its center coordinates and height & width are all dynamic. In that case how can I use this georeferencer?

Comment: (1) `imgOffsetsFromCenter` is image extent as you used it. Forgot to include it, corrected. (2) As I wrote, I didn't find way to calculate `imageScale`. You could experiment with different images and derive formula from the results (it it's linear), or you could try to find out the method from source code of ol-ext georeferencer at https://github.com/Viglino/Map-georeferencer

Comment: This GeoImage is not working for me. Is there any way other than using GeoImage for rotating an image in Openlayers?

Comment: The above is correct answer to your question why your GeoImage didn't show. If you don't like the facts or don't find them useful, answer is still answer. If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.